# randomize datetime column values for all existing entries

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

So, I got this dummy table for a showcase demo project I just built, so I started uploading posts in a sequential order, is there a way to modify or alter the datetime column to simply change it to random dates?

```
title    |  content   | date
title1   | xxxxxxxxx  | 2017-09-07 16:49:57
title2   | xxxxxxxxx  | 2017-09-07 16:49:57
```

So... what I'd like to do is to simply run a query so the date column stays something like

```
title    |  content   | date
title1   | xxxxxxxxx  | 2017-06-06 12:13:01 <- random generated date
title2   | xxxxxxxxx  | 2017-19-07 21:37:57 <- random generated date
```

Comment: https://mockaroo.com/ can be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a PRIMARY KEY (i.e. `id`) to do this with a self join update query.

If not, you can use the `title` instead to match the rows, but it would result in all posts with the same title ending up with the same random date:

```
/* convert date range to seconds to get an INT to express randomization range */
SET @min := UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE('Apr 15 2009 12:00AM', '%M %d %Y %h:%i%p'));
/* subtract the max ID from the range so we can add the ID later to the range 
 * without getting out of range values */
SET @max := UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE('Sep 08 2017 01:00AM', '%M %d %Y %h:%i%p')) - (SELECT MAX(id) FROM table);

/* join a second reference of the table as a source for the update */
UPDATE table AS target JOIN table AS source ON source.id = target.id
/* and add the source ID to the range to force the optimizer to calculate
 * a random number for each row independently */
SET target.date = FROM_UNIXTIME( ROUND((RAND()*(@max - @min + source.id))+@min) )
/* dont forget to link source and destination with the primary key! */
WHERE source.id = target.id
```